# JFileChooser cancel button returning APPROVE_OPTION

Tags: java

this is my first question here so please bear with me. I have this JFileChooser here, and even though I hit "Cancel" in the window, it returns APPROVE_OPTION as oppose to CANCEL_OPTION. It is a save dialog which I open like this

`returnVal_2 = fileChooser_2.showSaveDialog(frame);`

And here is the initialization and usage of it

```
fileChooser_2 = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (returnVal_2 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            savePath = fileChooser_2.getCurrentDirectory();
            System.out.println("yes");
        } else if (returnVal_2 == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("no");
        }
    }
});
```

It works as it's supposed to when I hit "Save" (which by the way, also returns APPROVE_OPTION).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistakenly checking the return value in an action listener. Your `actionPerformed()` method is being invoked *before* your file chooser has returned its result into `returnVal_2`. The reason you believe `APPROVE_OPTION` has been returned is because your variable is initially `0` and `APPROVE_OPTION` is also `0`.

Instead, forget about action listeners and just check the return value after the call to`showSaveDialog()`:

```
fileChooser_2 = new JFileChooser();
returnVal_2 = fileChooser_2.showSaveDialog(frame);

if (returnVal_2 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
  savePath = fileChooser_2.getCurrentDirectory();
  System.out.println("yes");
} else if (returnVal_2 == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
  System.out.println("no");
}
```

Comment: Makes sense now. I thought I had to use the file chooser's action listener to get what button was clicked in the window. Thanks!